# Login Angular - PHP error

Tags: angularjs

i'm creating an app with Angularjs and PHP, which try connect to file PHP of other Domain, but when i call the file it never show me the info.This my Controller...

```
myapp.controller('loginCtrl', function loginCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.doLogin = function() 
{        
    $http({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'http://www.domain.com/login.php?',
        data: 
        { 
            'usuario'   : $scope.usuario, 
            'password'  : $scope.password,
            'Type'      : 1
        },

    })  
    .success(function(data, status)
    {
        alert('Validado');
        $scope.data = data;
        if(data == 'No encontrado')
        {
            $scope.aviso = 'Usuario o contraseña invalidos';
        }
        else 
        {
            $scope.aviso = 'Bienvenido';
        }

    })
    .error(function(data, status) {

            $scope.data = data || "FALSE";
            $scope.status = status;  
            $scope.aviso = 'Ha pasado algo inesperado';
    });

};
```

});

And this is my Template...

```
<div  class="container">
    <hr>
    <div class="span5" > 
        <form>
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login </h2>
            <label>Usuario</label>
            <input type="text"      ng-model="usuario">
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password"  ng-model="password">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" ng-click="doLogin()" class="btn btn-primary">
            <div>{{aviso}}</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it never in to .success(), when i use Mozilla and Chorme the firebug is empty, but when i use:

```
 $http.get('http://www.domain.com/login.php?usuario=user1&password=123456&Type=1')
    .success(function(data, status).... appears the next error:

 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domain.com/login.php?usuario=user1&password=123456&Type=1. Origin http://localhost:8081 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have been unable to fix it, If somebody know the Answer I'll appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Look into CORS and cross domain AJAX AngularJS I believe you'll find what you need.

Comment: you have to enable cors in your web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a local proxy script or enable CORS. CORS is usable by most browsers, but not all. Using a local proxy script is probably the safest bet. Basically, all Ajax requests would go through the proxy passing the remote address to use thereby keeping in line with the same-domain access policy.

A good PHP proxy: https://github.com/eslachance/php-transparent-proxy

More on CORS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing